# How to get the string which is less than 4 using SED or AWS or GREP

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I'm trying to get strings which are less than 4 (0,3) characters which might include some special characters too.

The issue here is I'm not really sure what all special characters are involved

It can contain names of any length with some special characters not sure what all are included.

Sample Input data is as below

```
r@nger
d!nger
'iterr
4#e
c#nuidig
c@niting
c^neres
sample
```

Sample Output should be like this

```
r@n
d!n
'it
4#e
c#n
c@n
c^n
sam
```

I have tried below which both works but both has flaws apart from the 0,3 character strings I'm also getting only 1 character outputs which is incorrect.

Like just `C`, which I don't have in the input by itself

`grep -iE '^[a-z0-9\.-+?$_,@]{0,3}$'`

`sed -n '/^.\{0,3\}$/p'`
`grep uid: file.csv | awk {'print $2'} | sed -En 's/^([^[:space:]]{3}).*/\1/p' | sort -f > output`

Sample Output from above

- r@n
- d!n
- 'it
- 4#e
- c#n
- c
- c
- sam
- s

I'm thinking that there might be some special character after the first character which is making it break and only printing the first character.

Can someone please suggest how to get this working as expected

Thanks,

Comment: Can you try: `grep -E '^[^[:blank:]]{1,3}$' file`

Comment: Hi @anubhava, it still prints 1 characters like a,g,,u.

Comment: And why it should not print `a` as it has length less than 4?

Comment: you're right, but all those names are literally unique that's why it shouldn't have more than once it could be anything like this a_n or .a. also these are actual user IDs from ldap.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73952780/edit) your question and include a sample of your input with your expected output. Also mention finding unique requirement as well.

Comment: Are you running the output through another program, or piping this data into one of the tools? Are you sure the sample data is what you have specified? Using `^` and `$` are anchors for the start and the end of the string. You could write the sed command as `sed -En 's/^([^[:space:]]{3}).*/\1/p' file` for example, but the provided answers work for the given data.

Comment: @Thefourthbird, I'm piping this to sort and redirecting to the file.

Comment: @rshdzrt Can you update your question with the full command that you are using, perhaps that might make it more clear.

Comment: @Thefourthbird, grep uid: file.csv | awk {'print $2'} | sed -En 's/^([^[:space:]]{3}).*/\1/p' | sort -f > output

Comment: @rshdzrt  Please add that to the question.

Comment: @anubhava, j_b, Thefourthbird,  looks like I've found the issue I see that there is data with this format U Test.... so looks like when I was doing awk '{print $2}' it was only printing U, now that I have changed the entire command.

Answer (score 2):

To get the output you posted from the input you posted is just:

```
$ cut -c1-3 file
r@n
d!n
'it
4#e
c#n
c@n
c^n
sam
```

If that's not all you need then edit your question to more clearly state your requirements and provide more truly representative sample input/output including cases where this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{print (length($0)<3) ? $0 : substr($0,0,3)}' src.dat
```

Output:

```
r@n
d!n
'it
4#e
c#n
c@n
c^n
sam
1
11
-1
.
```

Contents of `src.dat`:

```
r@nger
d!nger
'iterr
4#e
c#nuidig
c@niting
c^neres
sample
1
11
-1
.
```

Comment: thanks @j_b, looks like this is just getting the first 3 letters/character no matter whatever the actual length is.

Comment: Updated answer per OP's comment.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `grep` with `-o` and `-E` options:

```bash
grep -oE '^[^[:blank:]]{1,3}' file

r@n
d!n
'it
4#e
c#n
c@n
c^n
sam
```

Regex `^[^[:blank:]]{1,3}` matches and outputs 1 to 3 non-whitespace characters from start position.

Comment: thanks @anubhava,  this is still giving me 1 letter non unique outputs.

Comment: But this is exactly what you showed as expected output in question.

Answer (score 0):

`sed 's/.//4g' file`

Delete every char starting at 4th until there aren't any more.  GNU sed, which says:

> Note: the POSIX standard does not specify what should happen when you mix the g and number modifiers, and currently there is no widely agreed upon meaning across sed implementations. For GNU sed, the interaction is defined to be: ignore matches before the numberth, and then match and replace all matches from the numberth on.

Also:  `grep -o '^...' file`